# Segmentation fault (core dumped), linux, g++

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, g++

I have a code that is compiles with g++ without any errors but if I run en executable and after entering the first integer value I get seg fault error. Previously this code was working fine but now I keep getting these messages. 
I am a beginner and I do not have any idea why this is happening. My code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int x, y, z,h,m,d,i, a[9][9];

bool f;

for(x==0; x<=8; x++){for(y==0; y<=8; y++){  
cin >> z; a[x][y]=z;


// y 
};
// x
};

do {

for(x==0; x<=8; x++){for(y==0; y<=8; y++){

if(a[x][y] == 0){

for(i==1 ; i<=9; i++){h=0; for(m==0; m<=8; m++){ 

if(y>=0 and y<=8){ if(a[x][8-m] != i){h++;};};

if(y>=0 and y<=8){ if(a[x][0+m] != i){h++;};};

if(x>=0 and x<=8){ if(a[8-m][y] != i){h++;};};

if(x>=0 and x<=8){ if(a[0+m][y] != i){h++;};};

if(h==16){a[x][y]=i; h=0;};
//lines

}; h=0;




// i
   };

// if 0
};

for(x==0; x<=8; x++){for(y==0; y<=8; y++){  
d=d+a[x][y];

// y 
};
// x
};

//y
};
// x
};



if(d==360){f==1;};
}

while(f==0);

if (f==1){for(x==0; x<=8; x++){for(y==0; y<=8; y++){  
cout << a[x][y];


// y 
};
// x
};
};


return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing y==0 , x==0 when you probably mean x=0,y=0

This can cause a seg fault and/or undefined behavior because x and y are still uninitialized so when you do a[x][y]= something you're attempting to write to an invalid memory address

example:

```
for(x==0; x<=8; x++){for(y==0; y<=8; y++){  
cin >> z; a[x][y]=z;


// y 
};
// x
};
```

becomes

```
for(x=0; x<=8; x++){
    for(y=0; y<=8; y++){  
        cin >> z; a[x][y]=z;     
    };// y 
};// x
```

Comment: Besides that there is also a problem with the curly braces. After the line with the `//if 0 ` the OP reuses x in another for loop altering values mid loop

Comment: Yep, that will cause OP's outer loop to terminate after 1 iteration